# How to use 15 length character key in flutter encrypt package

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I'm going to use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) package for encryption in the flutter application.
It doesn't accept keys lower than 16 characters long. But I want to use 15 characters key in length. Because in the backend, it was used this same key for encryption and decryption. So cannot change this key. What I need to do is, encrypt a plain text using the given 15 length characters key and send it to the backend via API.

In the Java backend, the below code is used to encrypt the file.

```
public SecretKeySpec generateKey(String myKey){
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = null;
        byte[] key;       
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            key = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            log.error("Error occured while generating key",e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            log.error("Error occured while generating key",e);
        }
        return secretKey;
    }
```

In my flutter application, this is how I've used the above encryption package.

```
final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8('fifteenCharactersKey');
final iv = enc.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);
final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(
      enc.AES(key), //, mode: enc.AESMode.cbc, padding: 'PKCS7'
    );
final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);

**enc is imported package {import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as enc}
```

Please give me an idea to generate the key with a 15 characters string.

Comment: In the Dart code the derivation of the 16 bytes key with SHA1 is missing. Note that a digest as key derivation and especially a broken one is insecure.

Comment: `encrypt` is just a wrapper over `pointycastle`. Consider using the latter directly so that you have more control. If you still want to use SHA-1 despite Topaco's sensible warning, it's available in `pointycastle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a solution.
As stated in the above java code, I got a byte array with 16 lengths using the given private key string.
The array is as below,

```
[-107, -23, -101, 71, 19, -45, -126, -59, -40, 38, -45, -85, -92, 17, -72, -81]
```

In flutter code, I converted extracted byte array to a Uint8List.

```
Uint8List x = Uint8List.fromList([-107, -23, -101, 71, 19, -45, -126, -59, -40, 38, -45, -85, -92, 17, -72, -81]);

final key = enc.Key(x);
final iv = enc.IV.fromSecureRandom(16);
final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(
  enc.AES(key,
    mode: enc.AESMode.cbc
  ),
);

final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
```